# Stackoverflow in kernel module

Tags: c, arrays, linux-kernel, kernel, stack-overflow

I reading a book "Linux Kernel. Development. Third Edition." by Robert Love.

What I read about stack size in this book:

> On x86, the stack size is configurable at compile-time and can be
>   either 4KB or 8KB. Historically, the kernel stack is two pages, which
>   generally implies that it is 8KB on 32-bit architectures and 16KB on
>   64-bit architectures—this size is fixed and absolute

I have VM with ubuntu 16.06 64-bit 4.15 kernel. So my stack size should be 16000 bytes (16KB)

I try to check stackoverflow behavior. I create array on the stack which use more than 16000 bytes.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

int __init overflow_start(void)
{
        printk(KERN_INFO "Overflow Test\n");
        char array[170000] = {[0 ... 16999] =  'A'};

        printk(KERN_ERR "%c\n", array[16999]);

        return 0;
}

void __exit overflow_end(void)
{
        printk(KERN_ERR "Test success\n");
}

module_init(overflow_start);
module_exit(overflow_end);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

I think that I should see kernel panic with stack smashing or something similar, but I see only correct output. Why it's not break the stack?

Comment: Probably because GCC can optimize it to `printk(KERN_ERR "%c\n", 'A');.`

Comment: @StoryTeller you are right!! I spend a lot of time with various length of array and miss such stuped thing. `ccflags-y  := -O0` throw warning and on `insmod` receive `BUG: unable to handle page request`

Comment: I might be wrong but I cannot imagine at all that Kernel programmers read the K in KB as 1000. I would bet it means 1024. So, 16 KB should be 16384 bytes. (I saw the `16999` in your code which made me stumble.) [XKCD: Kilobyte](https://xkcd.com/394/) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also make the array volatile and GCC won't optimize it.

```
volatile char array[170000] = {[0 ... 16999] =  'A'};
```

Comment: when I add `volatile` I have such warning `warning: the frame size of 340008 bytes is larger than 1024 bytes` why it think that my frame size is 340008 bytes?

Comment: That's because GCC doesn't optimize this expression `{[0 ... 16999] =  'A'}` so it allocates 2 arrays of 17000 bytes each.To avoid that you could do something like `volatile char array[170000] ; memset(array,'A',170000);`